# How to retrieve image or 'imagePath' through Dialog-Activity Communication?

Tags: android, image, interface, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have an `ImageView` opens a `dialog` with 2 options

1. to select photo from `External Memory`
2. or take new one using `Camera`

it opens the `dialog` and the dialog takes `permissions` successfully then open the camera or memory

but it gives me an `error` when i select photo from the memory or approve taken photo by camera

I am using `OnPhotoReceivedListener` `interface` in the `dialog` `fragment` to retrieve the `photo` and `imagePath`

Here is How i call the `Dialog` from the `Activity`

```
public class EditNoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ChoosePhotoDialog.OnPhotoReceivedListener{
private String mSelectedImagePath;

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_note);

      mSelectedImagePath = null;

    ImageView addImageIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAddImage);
    addImageIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*
            Make sure all permissions have been verified before opening the dialog
             */
            for(int i = 0; i < Permissions.PERMISSIONS.length; i++){
                String[] permission = {Permissions.PERMISSIONS[i]};
                if(checkPermission(permission)){
                    if(i == Permissions.PERMISSIONS.length - 1){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: opening the 'image selection dialog box'.");
                        ChoosePhotoDialog dialog = new ChoosePhotoDialog();
                        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "ChoosePhotoDialog");
                    }
                }else{
                    verifyPermissions(permission);
                }
            }
        }
    });

/**
 * Retrieves the selected image from the bundle (coming from ChoosePhotoDialog)
 * @param bitmap
 */
@Override
public void getBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getBitmapImage: got the bitmap: " + bitmap);
    //get the bitmap from 'ChangePhotoDialog'
    if(bitmap != null) {
        compressBitmap(bitmap, 70);
        //TODO: Save Image and get It's Url
    }
}

@Override
public void getImagePath(String imagePath) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getImagePath: got the image path: " + imagePath);

    if( !imagePath.equals("")){
        imagePath = imagePath.replace(":/", "://");
        mSelectedImagePath = imagePath;
        mImgUrls += StringManipulation.imgSerialize(new String[]{imagePath, "Description"});
        initRecyclerView(mImgUrls);
    }
}

public Bitmap compressBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int quality){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, stream);
    return bitmap;
}
```

and Here is my `Dialog class`

```
public class ChoosePhotoDialog extends DialogFragment {

private static final String TAG = "ChoosePhotoDialog";

public interface OnPhotoReceivedListener{
    public void getBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap);
    public void getImagePath(String imagePath);
}

OnPhotoReceivedListener mOnPhotoReceived;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_camera_or_memory, container, false);

    //initalize the textview for starting the camera
    TextView takePhoto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTakeCameraPhoto);
    takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting camera.");
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, Permissions.CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    //Initialize the textview for choosing an image from memory
    TextView selectPhoto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvChoosePhotoFromMemory);
    selectPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: accessing phones memory.");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, Permissions.PICK_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    // Cancel button for closing the dialog
    TextView cancelDialog = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCancelTakingPhoto);
    cancelDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: closing dialog.");
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        mOnPhotoReceived = (OnPhotoReceivedListener) getTargetFragment();
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "onAttach: ClassCastException: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    /*
    Results when taking a new image with camera
     */
    if(requestCode == Permissions.CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: done taking a picture.");

        //get the new image bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: received bitmap: " + bitmap);

        //send the bitmap and fragment to the interface
        mOnPhotoReceived.getBitmapImage(bitmap);
        getDialog().dismiss();
    }

    /*
    Results when selecting new image from phone memory
     */
    if(requestCode == Permissions.PICK_FILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        File file = new File(selectedImageUri.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: images: " + file.getPath());


        //send the bitmap and fragment to the interface
        mOnPhotoReceived.getImagePath(file.getPath());
        getDialog().dismiss();

    }
}
}
```

And this is the Error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65544, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:14786 flg=0x1 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }} to activity {com.ahmed_smae.everynote/com.ahmed_smae.everynote.EditNoteActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.ahmed_smae.everynote.Utils.ChoosePhotoDialog$OnPhotoReceivedListener.getImagePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Do you think the problem with the `interface` ?
How Can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your On your ActivityResult method. You are accessing a method on the interface of a null object.

Please set your debugger

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        mOnPhotoReceived = (OnPhotoReceivedListener) getTargetFragment();
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "onAttach: ClassCastException: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

Then confirm the getTargetFragment() is working.
As I suspect that this is returning null or it is getting nulled out at some point before you are accessing it.

mOnPhotoReceived appears to be null in your error, so then you should set a breakpoint at the point of which you are calling getImagePath() and see the object is null. Next you just need to see where/how it is set to null.

Comment: great observation. you are right i should use getActivity instead of getTargetFragment().

Comment: what if i want "take image" view to save the photo taken by camera and pass only the imagePath to the Activity. how can i do it

Comment: If you are using implicit intents, you have to accept the return type that they provide, but it is the imagePath already by default. So I'm not sure what you are asking as it already returns an image path to onActivityResult. If you are asking how to pass the path to a new activity, use a bundle intent and add a key / value pair where you pass the string path